# Дёргается Iframe на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, dle, playerjs

[image: Дергается плеер]

Есть у меня [сайт1](https://justdub.ru/), на котором ифрам с [сайта2](https://helium.justdub.ru/).
И просто ни с того ни с сего он дёргается.
Помогите, вообще не понимаю.

*php код генерирующий эту страницу на сайте2 [[тут]](https://controlc.com/d966b6c7)*

*код вывода на странице на сайте1*

```
    <div class="tab_box" id="pl">
        <iframe src="ссылка на стр на сайт2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen seamless> 
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ну очевидно же, что проблема в скролле. пропишите стиль `overflow: hidden` для iframe на сайте1 или для body на сайте2.

Comment: @Дима не обращайте внимание на комментарий. Это просто проверка условия получения секретной шляпы **Helping finger**

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий [@DiD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363135/%d0%94%d1%91%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-iframe-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5/1363148#comment2418744_1363135):

> ну очевидно же, что проблема в скролле. пропишите стиль overflow: hidden для iframe на сайте1 или для body на сайте2.

Добавил к `body` на сайте2, и все заработало. А вот если к `iframe` на сайт1, то не помогло.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: Так и должно было сработать в одном варианте из двух. Мне неизвестна ваша верстка, потому перечислил возможные варианты

Comment: @Дима не обращайте внимание на комментарий. Это просто проверка условия получения секретной шляпы **Helping finger**